# EhCache Cache and CacheWriter flush

Tags: java, ehcache

I am trying the write-behind functionality of Ehcache in order to achieve conflation for a high concurrent writes to a database. 
Right now, I have everything working (I write to the cache, and then under the configured policies), the cache is calling to my CacheWriter implementation for writing-behind.
However, I need at some point on time (for example, when the application is going to be shutdown, or in the integration tests), to "flush" all the pending cached values to the CacheWriter. 
In other words, I would like to call to Ehcache to "commit" all the dirty values to the CacheWriter.

Any idea in how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, I have tried: cache.flush(); without results...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use its shutdown listener: http://ehcache.org/documentation/operations/shutdown

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same issue, I've resorted to polling and waiting:

```
WriteBehindManager writerManager = (WriteBehindManager) cache.getWriterManager();
Stopwatch createStarted = Stopwatch.createStarted();
while (writerManager.getQueueSize() > 0 && createStarted.elapsed(TimeUnit.SECONDS) < 30) {
    Thread.yield();
}
```

Where Stopwatch is a timer object from the Guava library. I've browsed the sources but as of EHCache 2.9 there is no intentional flushing of the `WriteBehindQueue` to be found in the code. This solution assumes that any code that writes to the cache is also being shut down and that the `maxWriteDelay` + the latency of the last write actions don't add up to more than 30 seconds.